# Creating a list that links another list in Python/Java

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file from which I have to do some training from data.
This file contains some words.

I'd like to create a list which contains another list. The second list, is made of a key-value pair.

**For example:**

The word *Will* can be either a **name** or a **modal**.

My list should be something like that:

Will --> 1.[Key]Noun : [Value] *some-number* --> 2. [Key]Modal: [Value] *some-other-number*

How can I implement this in Python?

I believe that in Java this could be implemented using an Hashmap which contains another hashmap if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking of dictionaries, not lists.  Lists in python are akin to arrays, Dictionaries are as you guess similar to hashmaps, and can only have unique keys, but can hold other dictionaries.  You can also have a list of dictionaries, or a dictionary of lists.

For your project I'm just guessing you want something like.

`words={"Will":{"Noun":1,"Modal":2}}`
which you would then access by doing

```
>>> print(words)
{'Will': {'Noun': 1, 'Modal': 2}}
>>> print(words["Will"])
{'Noun': 1, 'Modal': 2}
>>> print(words["Will"]["Noun"])
1
>>> print(words["Will"]["Modal"])
2
```

Comment: Exactly! That was what i was looking for! Do I have to iinitialize it in a specific way, or a classic declaration is sufficient?

Comment: you can initialize a dictionary in a few ways `word={}` or `word=dict()` or initialize it like I did with data in it.  I am sure there are more ways.  You can then add and update elements with simple `word[key]=value` statements.  There are good tutorials here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp